# Is Android view the same as Control in .NET?

Tags: .net, android, view, controls

As the title says, I need a simple explanation: Is Android view the same as Control in .NET? As we have button view, textfield view, etc., it looks like it's the same as control in .NET.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kind of. The concept of a View in Android is more inline with the concept of a UIElement in WPF, in that it is a building block of the Android UI and WPF frameworks. A Widget in Android is more of a Control in the WinForms/WPF context.

Answer (score 1):

Broadly speaking, yes. They are each the foundation class for elements of their respective windowing systems.

Answer (score 1):

It's the same idea, just the different platforms' parlance for a UI widget. They serve the same purpose, but are definitely not the same exact thing. Different language, different OS, different hardware.